# How to add a joint to an existing skin cluster and set weights to zero with Maya MEL

Tags: maya, mel, maya-api

In Maya how do you add a joint influence to an existing skin cluster and set that joint skin weight to 0 using MEL script?

Answer (score 0):

```
skinCluster -e -weight 0.0 -addInfluence "jointName" "SkinClusterName";
```

[Reference documentation](https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2022/CHS/Maya-Tech-Docs/Commands/skinCluster.html)